# Looking for text character counting functionality in ahk

Tags: autohotkey

## Is there any text counting functionality in ahk?

I want to make an character counter where, if i press ctrl+alt+-, an input box will open. And the number of characters used in the variable‘s value will be counted.

`You can start with:`

```
<^<!-::
InputBox, Text1, Count, Paste the text in the text box to count the number of characters it has, and find things in that text
MsgBox text:You typed %Text1%.`nCharacters:
return
```

any answers? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [StrLen()](https://www.ahkscript.org/docs/commands/StrLen.htm) function retrieves the count of how many characters are in a string.

```
<^<!-::
    InputBox, Text1, Count, Paste the text in the text box to count the number of characters it has, and find things in that text
    if ErrorLevel
        return
    number_of_chars := StrLen(Text1)
    MsgBox text:You typed %Text1%.`nCharacters:%number_of_chars%
return
```